# Instagram basic display API for mobile

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Hey I am keen to use the OAuth display api on mobile phone but it seems that you have to default sign in even when you have logged into your Instagram app on mobile.

Is there a way to make it auto log in since users are already logged into their Instagram on their mobile?

Comment: it is a good practice to add some code examples, that you have already tried